Re-override plotly-resampler reset axis behavior
I created a Dash app that displays a figure in it. I have used plotly-resampler since I had to deal with large datasets.
At the documentation of plotly-resampler, they mentioned this:

The plotly autoscale event (triggered by the autoscale button or a
double-click within the graph), does not reset the axes but autoscales
the current graph-view of plotly-resampler figures. This design choice
was made as it seemed more intuitive for the developers to support
this behavior with double-click than the default axes-reset behavior.
The graph axes can ofcourse be resetted by using the reset_axis button.

However, I do would like to make sure that double clicking will reset the axis as it used to in the vanilla plotly.
Is there any ideas how to do it?
